# How to send email in Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-jde

I am developing an app where i need to send email from my app. I want to send email when button was clicked in my app. I executed the sample code given by Blackberry **"blackberrymaildemo"** but email is not sending from device & not getting any errors or exceptions also. I executed the following 
[Blackberry - How to send email using RIM API Tutorial](http://mobile-development.org/index.php/blackberry/blackberry-how-to-send-email-using-rim-api-tutorial-code-example) but not getting any idea how the code is running after app is launched as getting only blank screen & not getting any idea how to send email by the following code.

code:

```
    package mypackage;

   import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ButtonField;
   import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;
   import net.rim.blackberry.api.mail.Address;
   import net.rim.blackberry.api.mail.Folder;
   import net.rim.blackberry.api.mail.Message;
   import net.rim.blackberry.api.mail.MessagingException;
   import net.rim.blackberry.api.mail.Session;
   import net.rim.blackberry.api.mail.Store;
   import net.rim.blackberry.api.mail.Transport;


 public final class MyScreen extends MainScreen
 {
/**
 * Creates a new MyScreen object
 */
public MyScreen()
{        
    // Set the displayed title of the screen       
    setTitle("MyTitle");
    ButtonField btn = new ButtonField();
    btn.setLabel("Button Click");
    add(btn);

    try
    {
   Session session=Session.getDefaultInstance();
   Store store=session.getStore();

   Folder[] folders_list =store.list(Folder.SENT);
   Folder folder_sent = folders_list[0];

   Message message=new Message(folder_sent);

   message.setSubject("This is Test message");


    message.setContent("hi! this is test email from BB");


   Address recs[] = new Address[2];
   recs[0] = new Address("xxxxxx@gmail.com", "raghu b");
   recs[1] = new Address("xxxxxx@gmail.com", "b raghu");

   message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, recs);


   Transport.send(message);

    }catch (MessagingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


  }
 }
```

As i am new to this Blackberry development, i am unable get the code for sending email. Can anyone please help me with this.

When **share via email** button was clicked then the code of email needs to be invoked and my another doubt is can we send email or sms from blackberry simulator to another blackberry simulator/device...?

Thanks in advance..........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code -

```
Address recipients[] = new Address[1]; 
Store store = Session.getDefaultInstance().getStore(); 
Folder[] folders = store.list(Folder.SENT); 
Folder sentfolder = folders[0]; 
Message msg = new Message(sentfolder); 

try 
    { 
        recipients[0]= new Address("Email id","Name"); 
        //add the recipient list to the message 
        msg.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, recipients); 
        /set a subject for the message 
        msg.setSubject("Test email"); 
        //sets the body of the message 
        msg.setContent("123456789---------------"); 
        //sets priority 
        msg.setPriority(Message.Priority.HIGH); 
        //send the message 
        Transport.send(msg); 
      } 

      catch (Exception me) 
      { 

        System.err.print(me); 
      }
```

Comment: you have to configure the email in your device. It doesnt work on simulator.

Comment: Thanks for your code singnare but this is the same code i created in my app as posted above. Anyways thanks for the code again & as you said "you have to configure the email in your device. It doesnt work on simulator." how to configure email in our device....?

Comment: As per your code, i got one more doubt. When user is using my app in his device, is it possible to add some text in the body by user during runtime & send that email....?

Comment: use edit field to enter the subject. you have to activate blackberry internet service in your phone.

Comment: As per your code if we want to attach any attachment for our email means, what is the code need to follow..........?